# How to use tablet-only apps on normal 5 inch phone?

Tags: google-play-store

I want to install an app on my phone, Yu Yuphoria. However in play store it says your device is not compatible with this version and its not available for phones, it is only available for tablets. Is there any way to use it?
I tried Market Helper but it is not working either.

Comment: Could've just download APK from a trusted site and sideload it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a workaround you can use. You need to change the screen dpi to match that of a tablet.

•First of all you will have to install ADB. Download the tool from [here](http://adbdriver.com/downloads/). 
• Enable USB debugging.

•Now connect your phone to your PC. If you get notification. Click OK to allow USB debugging for that computer.

•Now open command prompt in ADB tool folder; Shift + Right-click in the folder and then click on open Command Prompt.

•Now you have to check whether your device is connected and ADB can detect it. To check enter the following code in the command prompt.

```
adb devices
```

Check current DPI with [DPI Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nick.mowen.dpichecker)

Proceed and change the DPI using the following command. In the following code the DPI is changed to 480. Change the value as you want DPI for your tablet.

```
adb shell wm density 480 && adb reboot
```

Just check the target DPI corresponding to a phone and use that value. In this example is 480.

•If you want to go back to previous DPI. Then enter the default DPI in place of the value previously changed.

Open playstore and see if you are now able to download the apps meant for tablet devices